# Product grid won't display correct number of columns, adds blank space- 1.9.1 RWD

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd

I have trouble with Magento 1.9.1 using the standard RWD,

I'm display products using the following code,

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="6" products_count="12" name="home.catalog.product.list"alias="products_homepage" category_id="3"template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

It doesn't matter what I set the column count at it will always not display the correct number of products on each row and also adds in blank space instead, the missing products are then displayed on the next line down,

See example here,

http://oilofcloves.com.au/store/

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

this is happening due to a lack of space. I have a solution although it will make it appear messy, you the edit following css. If you remove the margin-left attribute from the element .std ul li. You can find this in CSS file line 2056. This will remove the margin from each item and make enough space for 6 to fit but it will make appear messy as each item will be extremely close to each other.

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks for the response. Just with this, problem still occurs even if I set the number of columns to 3. In that situation it will show two columns of products and the white space.